# как найти точку зная длину вектора и углы в пространстве?

Tags: математика, геометрия, вектор, линейная-алгебра

Я знаю что на плоскости, зная длину вектора и его угол для нахождения точки достаточно сделать это:

```
x = cos(angle) * length
y = sin(angle) * length
```

Но я не знаю формулы чтобы сделать то же самое для пространства.
Вот что у меня есть:

```
angle1 = something
angle2 = something
length = something
```

Вот что мне надо узнать:

```
x = ?
y = ?
z = ?
```

Буду рад любой помощи!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Думаю, вы имеете в виду сферическую систему координат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Да? Тогда вот формулы преобразования:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Взято [отсюда](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82).